# MySQL Master at the same time slave?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have three MySQL Servers (5.1). On Server A and B i set up a Master-Master replication for some databases, lets say DX and DY.

Now i have a third server with another database DZ. I now want to replicate database DZ to Server A and B.

In the end, Server A and B replicates DX and DY. On server C there is only DZ that replicates to Server A and B.

It is also important that the databases DX and DZ are only available on Server A and B and didn't get replicated to Server C.

Normally i would configure Server A and B to be slaves for Server C for the single database. But a Master-Master replication works that Server A is a slave for Server B. And Server B is a slave for Server A. And it looks that it is not possible to configure more then one master, even for different databases?

Is this correct, or is there a solution to just replicate Database DZ from Server C to Server A and B, even if Server A and B already have a Master-Master replication running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in all versions upto 5.6, the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command can only accomodate one master and will change any existing master. So I think you are right, you can't do this currently.

Comment: Thanks, it really seems there is no possibility. I did now setup two MySQL Instances for this. It is not perfect but this solutions helps. MySQL have [mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html) for this, as a helper.